# Given a table containing class and students, need to find the diff in students

Tags: mysql, relations

I have class_students table where given 2 class ids I need to find the diff in students.
This is sql fiddle that I used,
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dba48e/11
Any help here.

Comment: Does your MySQL version is really 5.6? Specify it by using proper tag...

Answer (score 0):

Use, for example

```
SELECT student_id
FROM class_students
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING SUM(class_id = 1) > 0
   AND SUM(class_id != 1) = 0
```

More informative is

```
SELECT student_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT class_id) classes_in
FROM class_students
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT class_id) < ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT class_id)
                                    FROM class_students )
```

PS. Recommendation - define `(class_id, student_id)` (or in backward fields order) as unique/primary index - it will forbid duplicated records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN` instead of the MINUS operator to get the expected result, Since MySQL doesn't have MINUS operator.

```
SELECT a.student_id
FROM `class_students` a 
WHERE a.class_id = '1' 
AND a.student_id NOT IN (
    SELECT b.student_id
    FROM `class_students` b 
    WHERE b.class_id = '2'
)
```

Please find the [**working demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=66a14f779d5ae8bcd22092e82e972a49)

or using `LEFT JOIN` as

```
SELECT a.student_id
FROM `class_students` a 
LEFT JOIN `class_students` b ON b.student_id = a.student_id AND b.class_id = '2'
WHERE a.class_id = '1' AND b.student_id IS NULL
```

[**Working demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=21d32e4f8eff9db1d7db5af68a56ba37)

Comment: Does that find (A & NOT B) OR (B & NOT A) ?  I suspect it does only half of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  student_id AS student,
        (1 + 2) - class_id AS "is not in class"
    FROM  class_students
    WHERE  class_id IN (1,2)
    GROUP BY  student_id
    HAVING  COUNT(*) < 2;
```

Returns

```
student   is not in class
1         2
2         1
```

(Suggest you not use same numbers for students and classes.)